# Dynamic inherited entities based on JSON payload

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

So I have this `List<Vehicle> vehicles;` where `Vehicle` is the parent entity of 2 child entities `Car` and `Truck`. And what I'm trying to do is send a POST request and automatically the Service layer creates the respective objects for `Car` or `Truck` depending on the JSON payload.

`Vehicle`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicle")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Vehicle{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Integer index;

    public Vehicle() {
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

`Car`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car extends Vehicle {

    private Integer maxSpeed;

    private String brand;

    public Car () {
    }

    public Car(Integer index, Integer maxSpeed, String brand) {
        super(index);
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed ;
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

`Truck`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "truck")
public class Truck extends Vehicle {

    private Integer weight;

    private Double size;

    public Truck() {
    }

    public Truck(Integer index, Integer value, String period) {
        super(index);
        this.weight = weight;
        this.size= size;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

And the `JSON` would be something like this:

```
"vehicles": 
        [
            {
                "index": 1,
                "maxSpeed": "180",
                "brand": "Renault"
            },
            {
                "index": 0,
                "weight": 4000,
                "size": 25.0
            },
            {
                "index": 3,
                "weight": 3700,
                "size": 17.0
            },
            {
                "index": 2,
                "maxSpeed": "230",
                "brand": "Mercedes"
            }
        ]
```

And sending this JSON as a body of a POST request, I want to read each vehicle and create the respective type of vehicle (index 0 -> Truck, index 1 -> Car, etc) depending on their attributes.

Comment: maybe https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-nested-values#mapping-with-custom-jsondeserializer

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance

Comment: thanks, i'll take a look